# How to make ajax call that sends data to rails controller and returns data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, post, get, postgis

I'm making a Rails app that uses Leaflet. I have some pipes on my map and I want this functionality: when I click on the map, I get, as a response, how many pipes are within the distance of 50 miles. Now, in order to get this information, I need ST_Distance method from postgis, used on Pipe class (in the pipes_controller). Leaflet can get me the coordinates of the click, I need to send these to the controller, get it to calculate the number of pipes within 50 miles and return that number so it can be shown through javascript. I don't know how to get ajax to do this in one request, as a post/get method.

Help?

Answer (score 5):

This worked:

pipes_controller.rb

```
  def near 
    lat = params['coordinates']['lat']
    lon = params['coordinates']['lon']
    result = Pipe.where{ST_Distance(
              ST_Transform(location,26986),
              ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText("POINT(#{lat} #{lon})", 4326), 26986)) < 500}.count   
    rez = {"near" => result}
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: rez }  # respond with the created JSON object
    end
  end
```

Javascript:

```
function onMapClick(e) {
  var x = e.latlng.lng;
  var y = e.latlng.lat;
  var result;
  $.ajax({
    dataType: "text",
    url: "/pipes/near.json",
    type: "GET",
    data: {coordinates: {lat: x, lon: y}},
    success: function(json) {
      result = $.parseJSON(json);
      var answer="Number of pipes within 100m: " + result.near.toString();
      map.openPopup(answer, e.latlng);
    }
  });
};
map.on('click', onMapClick);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  max_zoom: 28
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for...if not please elaborate.As I understand the question you can do a standard ajax call, ex.

```
$.ajax(
      {
        url:'your-url',//this and the type will map to the controller action
        type:"POST",//or get
        data : 'you data',//the data you want to send to the controller
        dataType:'JSON',//or something else
        success:function(json)//json is the data controller send back
        {
          //success action

        },
        error: function(json) 
        {
           //error action here  
        }
      });
```

Comment: I tried this. I'm just not sure how to return value from controller, because I'm getting something weird.  Do I put return or result= or something?

Comment: What is the data format you are expecting to return? You can do a respond_to format.js block and create an js.erb file for the action..it will have all the ruby variables available. Or you can return as a JSON as format.json and parse the result in your success function. Let me know if it makes sense and if you can please paste the controller code here so people can help more :)

Comment: `data = {:near => result}.to_json`
`return data`